# Nested Scroll view vs Table View or something else for this requirement

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a requirement in which I need to have  the following functionality -

[image]

1)I have a custom segmented control. In order to implement paging to the segmented control I have used horizontal scroll view. Each page has its own vertical scroll view.

**Requirement**

1)The image should hide as user scrolls up in the respective pages and should show down when user scrolls down in respective pages but keeping the custom segment always at the top of the screen when image is hidden irrespective of the individual page selection-

[image]

**What I have tried so far -**

**1st Method**

I tried putting the image as header of a table view. 
Created a single section with one cell & gave the section header as the custom segment. And in the cell I placed the horizontal scroll view with the cell's height adjusted to cover all portion left out of the superview but it didn't work out as when I scroll the vertical scrolling of individual pages it was not in sync with the table view.

**2nd Method**

I tried setting the segment initially with a fixed distance from the top & I increased & decreased the constraint inside scrollViewDidScroll(). But it too didn't work as when the user scrolled rapidly ,the changing of constraint value didn't follow correctly.

**So is there any other way to achieve the same ?**
Please suggest as I can't make out what to do?

Comment: #@kamala Dash, did you find this solution? I also need this solution..could you help me as well?

Answer (score 2):

You add a `tableView` and your `UIImage` on top of it inside a `scrollView`. The `tableView` must have the same height & width than your `scrollView`. Then you disable the pan gesture of the `scrollView` :

```
self.scrollView.panGesture.active = false
```

Then you have to implement a custom scroll in `scrollViewDidScroll' of your`tableView`'s delegate:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 100 {
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.y += scrollView.contentOffset.y
        self.tableView.contentOffset.y = 0
    } else {
        // let the tableView scroll normally
    }
}
```

Or, you can have a try with https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar ;)

It's a great component that can handle many type on animation in the header based on the position of a `scrollView`.

Comment: https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar  only uses the parent scroll view. but remember I have multiple pages with independent vertical scrolling......

Comment: Why should I add the scroll view & then above it a table view. Okay can I send you a code that you can have a look. That would be quite helpful...!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/heerpg658r8j3gn/parallaxSecond.zip?dl=0 here is the link. Can you just please check